# C# access method concurrency

Tags: c#, .net-core, concurrency

I'd like to understand if there are some problems with concurrency passing an object to multiple classes. Example

```
class A: interfaceA{
    private object attribute;
    public A ()
    {
    }

    public bool doSomething(){
        Console.writeline("Happy new year :)");
        // other non static operations
    }
}

class B: interfaceB{
    private InterfaceA classA;

    public B(interfaceA classA){
       this.classA = classA;
    }

    public bool elaborate(){
       return classA.doSomething();
    }
}

class C: interfaceC{
    private InterfaceA classA;

    public C(interfaceA classA){
       this.classA = classA;
    }

    public bool elaborate(){
       return classA.doSomething();
    }
}


public void Main(){
   classA A = new classA();
   classB B = new classB(A);
   classC C = new classC(A);
  
}
```

This is a generic example just to give you an idea.
Thank you all :)

Comment: With specific code you shared, there won't be any problem.

Comment: Since you don't modify and/or read data concurrently, it's OK.

Comment: Both comments above are based on the fact that all your `interfaceA.doSomething()` does is a `Console.WriteLine("Static string");` which is threadsafe. The answer of this question very much depends on what `interfaceA.soSomething()` does

Comment: Please fix your sample code to be a valid C# code. interface name can't be started with `#` (CS1040)

Comment: What is the meaning of the hash sign (#) in your example?

Comment: # stand for "something" :) I removed it to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you all, for sure the method not call a simply static method. I have to implement some logic to manage the concurrency! I understood!

Comment: Are the interfaces `interfaceA`, `interfaceB` and `interfaceC` essential for the question? In case they are, I suggest to include them in the question. In case they are not, I suggest to remove them from the question, so that we can focus on what is important. It is also important that the code compiles. The `classA` is not defined in your example. Btw you should take a look at [C# naming conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md). Class and method names follow the PascalCase notation in C#.

Answer (score 1):

When writing multithreaded code you should be aware of the potential hazards. If you are not, then do not write multithreaded code!

As a general rule of thumb in .Net framework, static methods should be threadsafe, but instance methods are not, unless otherwise specified in comments. Your code happens to only call a static, threadsafe method. But you are likely to make the code non-thread safe if you make any changes to it.

There are plenty of resources describing the potential problems, far more than can be described here. For example [Microsofts best practices.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices) Or [jon skeets article on the subject](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/)